# CiviMail error when sending test

Tags: civimail

When sending a test email in CiviMail and we go to send a test we get the following: Error in call to Mailing_send_test : Validation failed for: "(INVALID)" <(INVALID)>.

We are running Civi Ver 4.16 on WordPress 4.5.4.

Email for other processes is fine and I have switched to SMTP and the same error occurs. Same issue occurs on production server & dev server (different boxes). The dev server hosts several WP/Civi site with no issues in CiviMail.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Here is the backtrace:

```
Nov 11 11:50:49  [info] $backTrace = #0 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(897): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(PEAR_Error))
#2 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(PEAR_Error))
#3 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(566): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("Validation failed for: \"(INVALID)\" ", NULL, 16, (Array:2), NULL)
#4 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Mail/RFC822.php(209): PEAR->raiseError("Validation failed for: \"(INVALID)\" ")
#5 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Mail.php(191): Mail_RFC822->parseAddressList("\"(INVALID)\" ", "localhost", FALSE)
#6 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Mail/mail.php(151): Mail->prepareHeaders((Array:10))
#7 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php(705): Mail_mail->send("\"Kilakwa Associates, LLC\" ", (Array:11), "--=_fc0b6ada5c5414641163756e3eafc23e\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\nConten...", "31")
#8 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php(607): CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob->deliverGroup((Array:1), Object(CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing), Object(Mail_mail), "", (Array:0))
#9 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php(196): CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob->deliver(Object(Mail_mail), (Array:12))
#10 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/Mailing.php(644): CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob::runJobs((Array:12))
#11 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_mailing_send_test((Array:10))
#12 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(96): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#13 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Subscriber/ChainSubscriber.php(196): Civi\API\Kernel->run("mailing", "send_test", (Array:10))
#14 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Subscriber/ChainSubscriber.php(72): Civi\API\Subscriber\ChainSubscriber->callNestedApi(Object(Civi\API\Kernel), (Array:35), (Array:5), "create", "Mailing", 3)
#15 [internal function](): Civi\API\Subscriber\ChainSubscriber->onApiRespond(Object(Civi\API\Event\RespondEvent))
#16 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(164): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(Civi\API\Event\RespondEvent))
#17 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(53): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch((Array:4), "api.respond", Object(Civi\API\Event\RespondEvent))
#18 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(221): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch("api.respond", Object(Civi\API\Event\RespondEvent))
#19 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(98): Civi\API\Kernel->respond(Object(Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider), (Array:9), (Array:5))
#20 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->run("Mailing", "create", (Array:35), NULL)
#21 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/REST.php(404): civicrm_api("Mailing", "create", (Array:35))
#22 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/REST.php(640): CRM_Utils_REST::process((Array:3), (Array:33))
#23 [internal function](): CRM_Utils_REST::ajax()
#24 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(278): call_user_func((Array:2))
#25 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:12))
#26 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#27 //public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1196): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#28 [internal function](): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#29 //public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(525): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
#30 //public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(236): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#31 {main}
```

Comment: It is remarkable that the call to Mail_mail->send has *Kilakwa Associates, LLC* as input instead of an email address.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was related to the from address. This install had been upgraded from 4.4 and CiviMail had not been used since then. The from_name and from_email fields in the civicrm_mailings table showed as (INVALID). When looking at the from address setup in Civi it looked fine. I retyped the entry and everything is fine now. ot sure what caused the from address to become invalid?